# Should I use Nextjs for writing just the FE code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, frontend

If I want to write my FE in React for which already a BE exists, should I use Nextjs or since I am not planning to write BE, it's better to use plain and simple React

Comment: Questions soliciting opinions and suggestions are not appropriate or encouraged here.

Comment: I'm not a Front-End developer. However, this question has no direct answer. One can have opinion on it. And for the best answerI can come up with: "It depends"

Comment: @Fedoruka https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201994/is-there-a-place-to-ask-opinion-based-questions

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depends on your needs. NextJS has several advantages in comparison  to pure React (like build-in route handling and server side rendering, etc.) but it could take more time to create application using it. Take a moment to think what you need from your application and then you'll be able to pick what fits you best.